# Trying to read a .tsv file where the first few lines contain an amount of fields different to the rest of the file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to read a tsv file containing a large amount of data to process later using python. Problem is, the first few lines of these tsv files follow a format (I'm not sure how to phrase it) that is different from the actual data.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
Name: Test 
Number: 213
LmaoIdk: Something else

Date   Measurement   Different_Measurement   Another_Measurement...
123    123           123                     123                ...
.
.
.
```

How would I go about reading this tsv file into python, while retaining all of the information in the tsv file? Thanks!

Currently I'm trying to use the pandas csv reader with the delimiter set to '\t' to read the file as per the following:

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv(r'filename.tsv', delimiter = '\t')
```

However, using this approach yields the following error message:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 27, saw 527
```

The desired outcome is that the tsv file is read into my code, and stored in a list.

Comment: I know it's easy to get lost in the myriad optional arguments to [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) but if you look carefully through the avaliable options you'll find one called `skiprows` which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there is a skiprows option in read_csv:

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv(r'filename.tsv', skiprows = 4)
```

This will skip the first 4 lines in the file

EDIT to read the first 3 lines, you can do this in 2 separate reads:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'filename.tsv', nrows = 3, header = None, delimiter = ':')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'filename.tsv', skiprows = 4)
```

df1:

```
         0                1
0     Name             Test 
1   Number              213
2  LmaoIdk   Something else
```

df2:

```
Date   Measurement   Different_Measurement   Another_Measurement
123    123           123                     123
```

Alternatively you could just read the first 3 lines using the with open as method, and split the lines into a list/dict

Comment: The thing is I need the information prior to the actual data as well so skipping rows wouldn't be the optimal solution. Would I be able to read the first few rows into a list, and then read the actual data into another?

Comment: yes see edit - you can basically split it into 2 separate reads